# android - how to check if device has connected to wifi without password?

Tags: android, android-wifi

I am building a feature that warns user if the wifi that the device is connected to has no password. Is that possible?

I've read this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkCapabilities

and this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager

And it seems I can get all the data I want (`SSID`, `BSSID` etc) but can't answer the main question: did the wifi require password or not.

Comment: How about if you check if a user is connected to a network but has no internet connection? Is that good enough? I guess there could be a few reasons for having no internet connection when connected to WiFi, one of them being not entering a password.

Answer (score 0):

It requires root access. If you have super user privilege you can use `WifiManager -> getPrivilegedConfiguredNetworks` to get the WiFi connectivity configs and check if the password is blank. Refer to [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/758bdf4a915c313f1c3bef0b95b494c91f363f03%5E%21/#F1).